# Error uploading ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

**Background:**

- This app was originally uploaded to my personal ionic account
- The app was deleted from my personal ionic account
- This error happens when I try to upload the app with my work ionic account

My question is, how do I get the app to upload to my work account?

```
$ ionic upload

Uploading app...
 ✗ App ID ae440d8c does not exist




Unable to upload app (CLI v1.4.5)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 4.3.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.22
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.1
Xcode version: Xcode 6.3.1 Build version 6D1002
```

Comment: open ionic.project file, set appId to blank, then try ionic upload. it will create new ionic id.and it will work.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

1. Log in at [apps.ionic.io](http://apps.ionic.io)
2. Create a new App and specify the name of your App.
3. Copy the App ID to your clipboard for use in the next step.
4. In your terminal window ensure you're logged into the same account that you were logged into on app.ionic.io).
5. In your terminal window use command:

   ionic link `<copied-app-id>`

   Where `<copied-app-id>` is your own App ID copied to your clipboard in step 3.
6. In your terminal window use command:

   ionic upload

Comment: Ensure u logged in on your terminal `ionic login`

Comment: updated to make the bit about being logged into the correct account in terminal clearer as per Sboniso's comment

Answer (score 22):

Get it solved with Chirag thaker's suggestion:

1. Open ionic.project.json (if not exist find ionic.config.json) file
2. Set appId to blank (delete the existing appId)
3. run `ionic upload` again

Answer (score 6):

I think this is because, your keys are now miss matching, so try

- Create a new app in (ionic.io)
- Get the `app key` and `public key`
- Add those to your existing app in

  *app.js / .config section*

  ```
   $ionicAppProvider.identify({
      app_id: 'APP_ID',
      api_key: 'PUBLIC_KEY',
      //gcm_id: 'YOUR_GCM_ID'
    });
  ```
- try uploading again

Answer (score 4):

In folder root project run:

```
ionic io init
```

> https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Even after reading everything it still looked confusing to me so re-producing here solution again so others can easily resolve it.

Here are the steps:

1. Login https://apps.ionic.io/apps and Create new App.
2. Replace your current App ID in your `ionic.config.json` file against `app_id` with the help of below screenshot.[image]
3. Now run `ionic upload`, and you should no more see the error :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem..
Sameera207 is almost correct but not quite for my case. ( I don't believe Ionic even looks in your angular JS files )

I think this is because, your ID does not yet exist in apps.ionic.io, so try

- Create a new app in (ionic.io)
- Get the app ID
- replace the app IP to your existing app in

ionic.project file

```
{
  "name": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
  "app_id": "YOUR_APP_ID"
}
```

- try uploading again

Answer (score 0):

Also note, that sometimes ( not sure why and when ) the following command:

```
ionic package build android --release
```

is truncating the file:

```
.io-config.json
```

Making it empty, so it also prevent you from uploading your app again.

Answer (score 0):

i just delete my ionic.project file and re-run ionic upload

Answer (score 0):

To resolve

1. login to to you ionic.io and create an app in
   https://apps.ionic.io/apps
2. Copy the new App Id
3. On you development system, go to your project folder and edit ionic.config.json. Update the "app_id" to new id that you copied in step 2. Save file.
4. From your ionic project run the command: ionic upload.

Answer (score -1):

You can reset the io-app-id with the following command then try uploading your app again

```
ionic link --reset
ionic upload
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `.io-config.json` from the build root; run `ionic io init`; then try to upload again.